# Enabled Multicurrency in Org

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, multi-currency, currency

I have enabled multicurrency in org ,but the CurrencyISOCode field got added to all Objects PageLayouts.
I want to remove this field from all pagelayouts.Please suggest .
i have almost 600 objects and 1000 Pagelayouts where this field is added.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Eclipse to pull out all page layouts and do a global search and replace for `<field>CurrencyIsoCode</field>` to ``